# get the data in recyclerview

Tags: mysql, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Hello everyone i am getting the messages of the users in android studio for that i am refreshing the recyclerview every second but the probem is scrolling when i am scrooling the recyclerview to old messages then its not scrooling becouse of the getting data every second can someone please help me in this

bellow is my activity code

```
public class Message_User_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_user);

        content();
        Clicks();
    }

    public void content()
    {
        getdata();
        refresh(100);
    }

    private void refresh(int milliseconds)
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                content();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,milliseconds);
    }

    private void getdata()
    {
        toolbar_user_name.setText(name);
        String Choice = "Get Messages";
        Call<List<responsemodel>> call = SplashScreen.apiInterface.getfullprofiledata(Choice,Message_To,Message_From);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<responsemodel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<responsemodel>> call, Response<List<responsemodel>> response) {
                List<responsemodel> data = response.body();
                Message_user_Adapter adapter = new Message_user_Adapter(data,Message_To);
                messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() -1);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<responsemodel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

below is my adapter code

```
public class Message_user_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Message_user_Adapter.Message_user_Adapter_View_Holder>
{

    List<responsemodel> data;
    String mmessage_To;

    public Message_user_Adapter(List<responsemodel> data, String message_To) {
        this.data = data;
        this.mmessage_To = message_To;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Message_user_Adapter_View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_messages_layout,parent,false);
        return new Message_user_Adapter_View_Holder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Message_user_Adapter_View_Holder holder, int position) {

        String time = calculateTime(data.get(position).getMessage_Time());

        if (data.get(position).getMessage_From().equals(mmessage_To))
        {
            holder.other_user_message_message_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.other_user_message_message_layout.setText(data.get(position).getMessage() + "\n \n" + time);
            holder.message_message_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else
        {
            holder.other_user_message_message_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.message_message_layout.setText(data.get(position).getMessage() + "\n \n" + time);
            holder.message_message_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private String calculateTime(String post_time)
    {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            long time = sdf.parse(post_time).getTime();
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CharSequence ago =
                    DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
            return ago+"";
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public String getdata() {
        return mmessage_To.toString();
    }

    class Message_user_Adapter_View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView other_user_message_message_layout;
        TextView message_message_layout;
        CircleImageView toolbar_user_profile;

        public Message_user_Adapter_View_Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            other_user_message_message_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.other_user_message_message_layout);
            message_message_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_message_layout);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**According to my simple information**
in your `getdata()` function. you send new data to `Message_user_Adapter` of `RecyclerView` every time you receive data from API or whatever you use ,so the data of adapter every second is change to new data ,so the `RecyclerView`  being recreated every second with new data and the scroll will not work

just try to outage this lines from `onResponse` to the first of `getdata()`:

```
Message_user_Adapter adapter = new Message_user_Adapter(data,Message_To);
messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and in its place add this line to notify the adapter about changed data :

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

something like this :

```
private void getdata() {
    toolbar_user_name.setText(name);
    String Choice = "Get Messages";
    List<responsemodel> data = new ArrayList<>();//this line was change
    Message_user_Adapter adapter = new Message_user_Adapter(data,Message_To);//this line was change
    messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);//this line was change
    Call<List<responsemodel>> call = SplashScreen.apiInterface.getfullprofiledata(Choice,Message_To,Message_From);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<responsemodel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<responsemodel>> call, Response<List<responsemodel>> response) {
            data = response.body();
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()//this line was added
            messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages_Message_user_RecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() -1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<responsemodel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Actually I am using retrofit library for storing and getting data in mysql
And the data function which I use in on response is actually I am getting message data then after getting the data I send it to adapter and then set the adapter for the recycler view as you can see in my getdata() function
So if I use the data function above from the on response then what data will get